# Error (193) C no es una aplicación Win32 válida

Tags: python, pycharm, mpi

Tengo el siguiente programa en python e intento ejecutarlo desde la consola con `mpiexec -n 2 test.py`

El código de `test.py` es este:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD   # Defines the default communicator
num_procs = comm.Get_size()  # Stores the number of processes in num_procs.
rank = comm.Get_rank()  # Stores the rank (pid) of the current process
print("Hello world, say process ! ",rank)
```

Y la salida es el error del titulo de la pregunta:

> (venv) C:\Users\vycto\PycharmProjects\Prueba_mpi4py>mpiexec -n 2
>   test.py ERROR: Error reported: failed to launch 'test.py' on
>   DESKTOP-6M6P2G5 Error (193) C no es una aplicaci¾n Win32 vßlida.

Estoy usando `PyCharm` como IDE, tengo `Python 3.7.3` y la versión más actual de `MPI para Windows 10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, el problema es literalmente lo que especifica la salida del programa. No es un programa que se pueda ejecutar sobre Windows, entonces, hay que ejecutarlo antes con py o python en la consola.

Así: `mpiexec -n 2 python test.py`